# posts not updated when querying posts by likes and time from firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to list the posts by likes and time. But the list is not updating. Newer posts with more likes are not shown. I have 'posts' collection and 'likes' collction, which are updated with the like button press:

```
return IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (docs.isEmpty) {
            likesRef.add({
              'userId': currentUserId(),
              'postId': widget.post.reviewId,
              'dateCreated': Timestamp.now(),
            });
            postRef.doc(widget.post.reviewId).update({"likes": 
 FieldValue.increment(1)});
            addLikesToNotification();
          } else {
            likesRef.doc(docs[0].id).delete();
            postRef.doc(widget.post.reviewId).update({"likes": 
  FieldValue.increment(-1)});
            removeLikeFromNotification();
          }
        },
```

and then I query the posts:

```
  StreamBuilderWrapper(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      stream: postRef.orderBy('likes', descending: true)
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).snapshots(),
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (_, DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
        internetChecker();
        Review posts = Review.fromJson(snapshot?.data());
        return posts.reviewId != null
            ? Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0),
          child: Posts(post: posts),
        )
            : Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(language?.noReviews ?? ""),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```

My Firestore rules are pretty simple:

```
match /reviews/{userId=**} {
allow read, delete, update, create: if request.auth != null;
}

match /notifications/{userId=**} {
allow create, read, update, delete: if request.auth != null;
}

match /comments/{userId=**} {
allow read, delete, update, create: if request.auth != null;
}

match /likes/{userId=**} {
allow read, create, delete, update: if request.auth != null;
}
```

is my 'likes' adding method correct? where could be the issue? where else should I look? Very new to Firestore and developing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for such late response. I am not sure if its related but I saw this: "Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction". Reading on this...

Comment: That look more like an error of SQL Lite for Flutter. We would need more concrete descriptions of your erros and what is not working.

Comment: other than that i dont have any errors in log. is my 'likes' incrementing correct? I am not sure, as I noticed that in my firestore, the reviews' 'likes' not updated... I need help :D

Comment: I have similar streams: by time only, by ratings and time, and array by saved posts. And only by 'likes' is the one that is not updated. So, I assumed that there is an issue with the 'likes' field...

Comment: Can you make a screenshot when that error happens of the logs.

Comment: I am so stupid! I had a mistake in my likes incrementing 'widget.post.reviewId'! I fixed it to the correct path and it worked. Need to pay more attention to details. Thanks for the effort! :)